# How to implement floor modulo for every Number type in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, modulo

I'm currently learning Kotlin and trying to create an extension (infix) method that works on all [number types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#numbers) (`Byte`, `Long`, `Float`, etc.). It should work like Python's `%` operator:

```
 4   %   3  ==   1      // only this is the same as Java's %
 4   %  -3  ==  -2
-4   %   3  ==   2
-4   %  -3  ==  -1
```

...or like Java's [`Math.floorMod`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floorMod-int-int-), but it should also work with `Double` or `Float`:

```
-4.3 %  3.2 ==   2.1000000000000005
```

or with any possible combination of these types

```
 3   %  2.2 ==   0.7999999999999998
 3L  %  2.2f ==   0.7999999999999998
```

The following works as intended, but only for two `Double` or two `Int`:

```
inline infix fun Double.fmod(other: Double): Number {
    return ((this % other) + other) % other
}

inline infix fun Int.fmod(other: Int): Number {
    return ((this % other) + other) % other
}

// test
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("""
            ${-4.3 fmod 3.2} == 2.1000000000000005

            ${4 fmod 3} == 1
            ${+4 fmod -3} == -2
            ${-4 fmod 3} == 2
            ${-4 fmod -3} == -1
    """)
}
```

Replacing `Int` with `Number`, I get the following error messages:

```
Error:(21, 18) Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
@InlineOnly public operator inline fun BigDecimal.mod(other: BigDecimal): BigDecimal defined in kotlin
Error:(21, 27) Public-API inline function cannot access non-public-API 'internal open fun <ERROR FUNCTION>(): [ERROR : <ERROR FUNCTION RETURN TYPE>] defined in root package'
Error:(21, 36) Public-API inline function cannot access non-public-API 'internal open fun <ERROR FUNCTION>(): [ERROR : <ERROR FUNCTION RETURN TYPE>] defined in root package'
```

How can I achieve this for every number type without copy-pasting this for every type combination?

Comment: The abstract class `Number` doesn't have a member function called `mod` nor `plus`. That could be the cause of the error.

Comment: do not inline the operator, it may slow down the execution

Comment: @voddan Doesn't inlining exist to improve the performance since no function call is required?

Comment: the performance will probably be hurt in this case because the size of the binary will increase due to duplication. If necessary, JVM inlines methods on its own. If you inline a method yourself, JVM can not know that the code is duplicated and needs further optimisations.

Comment: if you want to optimise, you should look for small binary size, which would allow to use CPU code cashes more effective. The only more costly thing than memory access is memory allocation. That's why inlining a lambda and avoiding an object allocation improves performans

Comment: @voddan Nice to know! Thanks! Just to repeat: If I implemented the `fmod` for all the various Number type combinations (`infix fun Byte.fmod(other: Float)`, `infix fun Long.fmod(other: Double)`), inlining would still be bad for performance, correct?

Comment: I have no idea without actual measurements and statistics from your code base. I am only guessing here. But generally speaking, there is a good reason why there is no `inline` in Java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only reasonable option (also the fastest) is to define the operator for each pair of types you want to support:

```
infix fun Double.fmod(other: Double) = ((this % other) + other) % other

infix fun Int.fmod(other: Int) = ((this % other) + other) % other

infix fun Double.fmod(other: Int) = ((this % other) + other) % other

infix fun Int.fmod(other: Double) = ((this % other) + other) % other
```

That way the decision of what type to use is made by the compiler, not at the runtime. Those functions are not generic and do not use inheritance (read `Number`), which means that the values are not boxed (see Java primitive boxing), meaning that objects are not allocated.

I strongly do not recommend inlining those functions. Leave minor optimizations to JVM. The fact that objects are not allocated is the biggest performance win here.

P.S The number of functions grows as a square of types supported. Are you sure you need to support *all* types?

Answer (score 1):

After several minutes toying around, I came up with a dirty approach to do what you want:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal
import java.math.BigInteger

inline infix fun <reified T: Number> T.fmod(other: T): T {
  return when {
    this is BigDecimal || other is BigDecimal -> BigDecimal(other.toString()).let {
      (((BigDecimal(this.toString()) % it) + it) % it) as T
    }
    this is BigInteger || other is BigInteger -> BigInteger(other.toString()).let {
      (((BigInteger(this.toString()) % it) + it) % it) as T
    }
    this is Double || other is Double -> other.toDouble().let {
      (((this.toDouble() % it) + it) % it) as T
    }
    this is Float || other is Float -> other.toFloat().let {
      (((this.toFloat() % it) + it) % it) as T
    }
    this is Long || other is Long -> other.toLong().let {
      (((this.toLong() % it) + it) % it) as T
    }
    this is Int || other is Int -> other.toInt().let {
      (((this.toInt() % it) + it) % it) as T
    }
    this is Short || other is Short -> other.toShort().let {
      (((this.toShort() % it) + it) % it) as T
    }
    else -> throw AssertionError()
  }
}

assert(BigDecimal("2.1") == BigDecimal("-4.3") fmod BigDecimal("3.2"))
assert(BigInteger("2") == BigInteger("-4") fmod BigInteger("3"))
assert(2 == -4 fmod 3)
assert(2L == -4L fmod 3L)

assert(0.7999999999999998 == 3 fmod 2.2)
assert(0.79999995f == 3L fmod 2.2f)
```

I though `reified` would make casting (smart and explicit) unnecessary but it was not the case. Maybe I'm missing something (I'm new to Kotlin after all).

Comment: @voddan Do you mean mixed operators? If that's the case: no. Both operators must be of the same type.

Comment: as far as I understand, that was the initial requirement of the question

Comment: @voddan Yes, it should work with different types and the solution should also be very fast if possible. Thank you though EPadronU! I didn't know you could use `is` like that with `when`.

Comment: Maybe somebody can improve its performance but my last modification should allow mixed operators without any troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a completely generic higher-order-function approach without any reflection or casting:

```
inline fun <T> T.fmod(other: T, mod: T.(T) -> T, plus: T.(T) -> T) =
     this.mod(other).plus(other).mod(other)

assert(BigDecimal("2.1") == BigDecimal("-4.3").fmod(BigDecimal("3.2"), BigDecimal::mod, BigDecimal::plus))
assert(2L == -4L.fmod(3L, Long::mod, Long::plus))
```

However, it's not so pretty.

Comment: kind of useless in this context, don't you think? ;)